# Going from data to asyncData

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I am having some issues with Nuxt and server side rendering of my products. So I am trying to convert my data method to asyncData. However, things are not going as planned. I am unsure of what my issue is.

This code works, but is without asyncData.

```
export default {
  components: {
    CldImage,
    CldTransformation,
    CollectionHeader,
    Loading,
    Footer
  },
  head() {
    return {
      title: this.title,
      meta: [
        { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'lorem ipsum' }
      ]
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    cloudinaryCloudName: process.env.cloudinaryCloudName,
    popularProducts: [],
    loadingPopularProducts: false,
    title: 'website.com'
  }),
  mounted() {
    this.loadingPopularProducts = true
    axios.get('/api/v1/products?popular=true&limit=6').then((response) => {
      this.popularProducts = response.data.results
      this.loadingPopularProducts = false
    })
  }
}
```

Here is my go at asyncData, but I receive the catch "Products not found".

```
export default {
  components: {
    CldImage,
    CldTransformation,
    CollectionHeader,
    Loading,
    Footer
  },
  head() {
    return {
      title: this.title,
      meta: [
        { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: 'lorem ipsum' }
      ]
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    cloudinaryCloudName: process.env.cloudinaryCloudName,
    loadingPopularProducts: false,
    title: 'website.com'
  }),
  asyncData({ params, error }) {
    return axios.get('/api/v1/products?popular=true&limit=6')
      .then(response => {
        const popularProducts = response.data.results
        return { popularProducts }
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        error({ statusCode: 404, message: 'Products not found' })
      })
  }
}
```

without a catch I get this error

```
(node:14916) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1054:14)
(node:14916) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 26)
```

Comment: Use Postman, make the request through there. If it's the same issue, then the problem is with the proxy that webpack dev middleware employs.

Comment: How do you use the async function return value? Maybe you are confused in what your return gives you back but the return value of `asynData()` is not the result of your promise. It is the whole function.

Comment: @Michelangelo That's fine - https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data#returning-a-promise

Comment: @MichalLevý Ah I see. But are you using the merge correctly then? Shouldn't the return in the `then` callback be `{ popularProducts : response.data.results }` and in your template something like this: `<template>
  <h1>{{ popularProducts }}</h1>
</template>`

Comment: Are you using Nuxt's [Axios Module](https://axios.nuxtjs.org) ? From the code it seems you are not. Can you share your Axios setup?

Comment: @MichalLevý Ah, thought you were OP. Yeah seems to me OP is not using async correctly or at least not returning something meaningful for the template. Should be like an observable, right? Don't have much experience with Axios but I thought I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers. I had a friend take a look at it, and this was the result that worked for me.

```
  async asyncData(context) {
    const url = '/api/v1/products?popular=true&limit=8'
    const data = await context.app.getAsyncData(url)
    return { popularProducts: data.results ? data.results : [] }
  }
```

Just wanted to post the answer.